# Randomizing node tree that is not working as expected

Tags: texturing, shaders, shader-nodes

I created this randomizer that should be able to output one of two input colors randomly. I understand that using a *White Noise Texture* should return a value from 0.0 to 1.0.

So I should be able to feed that value into a greater than *Math* node that returns 1 or 0 to the fac of a *MixRGB* node if the input value is greater than 0.5. The problem is that it seems this isn't working as expected or isn't as reliable as expected.

I have done some testing and it seems that only one of that values is returned 100% of the time. What am I doing wrong here, or maybe is there a better node setup for randomizing?

[image]

Comment: Well, depends on what you are doing to change the value? That would be interesting to know. I haven't put them in a group, but I have taken _White Noise Texture_, _Greater Than_ and _Mix RGB_ nodes and plugged the _Color_ output into the _Base Color_ of a _Principled BSDF_ node. I have red and blue as colors. When I change the W value in the _White Noise Texture_ node, the color switches between red and blue. How are you doing it, because just looking at _Group Input_ and _Group Output_ nodes does not really show how you try to switch values.

Comment: Adding to what Gordon Brinkmann said, the [White Noise Texture](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/render/shader_nodes/textures/white_noise.html) generates it output depending on the input seed. It does *not* generate a completely random output on its own. If the seed remains constant, so does the output. Does that answer your question?

Comment: Essentially it's an integer that's being passed down through a few node tree's into a collection of these that should be driving randomization. Maybe that value is being converted somewhere into just a constant value that would explain why I'm having the issues I'm having. So if say a value 2 is seeded into a white noise texture the output of that white noise would always be the same?